# MySQL: Calculating Data from Table with One Month Offset

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am pretty new to SQL, so forgive me if this is a noob question. I am building a stored procedure that queries from a table that has data stored by month. Here is a simplified example of what the table looks like:

```
+------------+------------+------------+
|    date    |  value_A   |  value_B   |
+------------+------------+------------+
| 2014-01-01 |    100     |    200     |
| 2014-02-01 |    200     |    400     |
| 2014-03-01 |    300     |    600     |
| 2014-04-01 |    400     |    800     |
| 2014-05-01 |    500     |    1000    |
| 2014-06-01 |    600     |    1200    |
| 2014-07-01 |    700     |    1400    |
|    ...     |    ...     |    ...     |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

In the procedure, I need to calculate: (`Value_A / Value_B`). However, Value_B needs be lagged one month behind. So in the example above, the calculation for February 2014 would be: (`Value_A of Feb 2014 / Value_B or Jan 2014`) or (`200 / 200`). The calculation for March 2014 would then be: (`Value_A of Mar 2014 / Value_B of Feb 2014`) or (`300 / 400`), and so on and so forth. Hope that makes sense.

It wouldn't be too difficult to do if I was only querying a specific month since I could use a `CASE` statement in the procedure. But since I need to retrieve a year's worth of data grouped by month, I am a bit stumped.

Without the one month lag of Value_B, I have the SQL statement set up like:

```
SELECT ex.`date `, ex.value_A / ex.value_B AS calc
  FROM example_table ex
 WHERE ex.`date` BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2015-02-01'
GROUP BY ex.`date`
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. I've experimented with different joins and unions but haven't had any luck. Do I need to query Value_A and Value_B separately with their own date range, then merge them together somehow for the calculation? Or am I making this much harder than it really is?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t.date, t.value_A/t2.value_B AS calc
FROM table t JOIN table t2 ON t.date = DATE_ADD(t2.date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Comment: A simple code snippet is not enough, give textual explanation too (and do it fast, this answer will be probably shortly deleted)!

Comment: This did the trick. I never though to use DATE_ADD when joining the same table on the date. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help i think i read your question correctly...

```
SELECT ex.`date`, ex.value_A / ex2.value_B as calc
FROM test ex
LEFT JOIN test ex2 
    ON DATE_ADD(ex.`date`, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) = ex2.`date`
WHERE ex.`date` BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2015-02-01'
GROUP BY ex.`date`
```

Comment: Your answer is very close. When testing your SQL, it was lagging Value_A one month behind instead of Value_B. Either way, it helped me understand that I need to join the same table on the date field (both you and Javaluca suggest that in your answer). Thanks for the help!